# CakePHP 3.7.6 LegacyPasswordHasher dont work

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a problem with the auth component of cakephp
i follow this guide to create the legacypasswordhasher https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html
i load the class in the appcontroller like this:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Legacy',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

and i have created the legacypasswordhelper class in src/Auth like this:

```
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\AbstractPasswordHasher;

class LegacyPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher
{

public function hash($password)
{
    return sha1($password);
}

public function check($password, $hashedPassword)
{
    return sha1($password) === $hashedPassword;
}
}

?>
```

but if i login in my form the auth component dont run legacypassword functions. i use debugs in the hash and check function but it never shown.
i hope anyone have a solution

Answer (score 0):

ok, i solve this problem.
i didn't know that cake auth only works when you use the form function of cake.
i have worked with a normal form

```
<form method="post" action="/users/login">
```

but you really have to

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>
```

use it to make the legacy function work